# Show image based on calculated column value

Tags: calculated-column-formula

Why does SharePoint not understand to change the image when I use If statements? Specifically when I use it on a calculated culumn.

Building a status (project/risk) page and I use Probabiliy and Impact (1-3) to score the status/risk. No problem, then I use a calculated column to show images based on the value of the two combined(1-9 (green, Yellow, red).

If I point the calculated column to one of the values (Probability or Impact) I can get the image to change based on the value, but when I aim the column at the combined value it seems to not understand the value, all I get is a green light?!

The syntax seems to be right since i can get the result on the individual values, but not the combined...

Here is the formula i use in the caolculated culumn, by the way.

```
="<center>"&
    IF([Risk_value]<="4","<img src='/sites/111607/CDC_STHLM/SiteAssets/Status_pic/Green.gif' border='0'/>",
    IF([Risk_value]="6","<img src='/sites/111607/CDC_STHLM/SiteAssets/Status_pic/Orange.gif' border='0'/>", 
    IF([Risk_value]>"6","<img src='/sites/111607/CDC_STHLM/SiteAssets/Status_pic/Red.gif' border='0'/>")))
    &"</center>"
```

Comment: Please also post the formula for the individual columns that are working.

Comment: Same code, just different goal column, so rather than "IF([Risk_value]" just IF([Impact], that is one of the two columns that "Risk_value" is built on.

I realised that the problem was with me using the wrong format, text instead of numbers ("4" rather than just a plain 4)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide the formula you've added in the calculated column formula field , since there are certain format need to be maintained while combining multiple columns in the calculated column formula field.

Please refer the below link for more info on this topic:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Here it is, it seems to be cut in the original:
="<center>"&
 IF([Risk_value]<="4","<img src='/sites/111607/CDC_STHLM/SiteAssets/Status_pic/Green.gif' border='0'/>",
 IF([Risk_value]="6","<img src='/sites/111607/CDC_STHLM/SiteAssets/Status_pic/Orange.gif' border='0'/>", 
 IF([Risk_value]>"6","<img src='/sites/111607/CDC_STHLM/SiteAssets/Status_pic/Red.gif' border='0'/>")))
 &"</center>"

Answer (score -1):

Numeric value needs to be used because the `Risk_value` field is a number, e.g. `=4`, NOT `="4"`